# What is the adjacency matrix of a squared (or k^th power) d-regular graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a $d$-regular graph, then I suppose $A'$(the adjacency matrix of the squared graph) should be $A^2 + A - dI$ (to remove self-loops). What about higher powers? How do we remove self-loops from the final matrix?